# $4$ and $a_{2n + 1}$ are coprime?

Tags: number-theory, induction

Suppose $a_i$ is a sequence of positive integers. Define $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 2$ and $a_{n+1} = 2a_n + a_{n-1}$. Does it follow that

$$ \gcd(a_{2n+1} , 4 ) = 1 $$ ???

Im trying to see this by induction assuming above holds, we need to see that $\gcd(a_{2n+3} , 4 ) = 1$.

But, $\gcd(a_{2n+3} , 4 ) = n_0(2a_{2n+1} + a_{2n-1}) + 4n_1$ for integers $n_0, n_1$. But this quantity does not seem to give me $1$. Can someone help me with this problem? thanks

Comment: Clearly $a_{n+1} \equiv a_{n-1} \bmod 2$ for all $n$. Also $a_1$ is odd so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your inductive step. Note that the statement $gcd(a,4)=1$ says just that $a \bmod{2} = 1$. So, here is the inductive step:
$$ (a_{2n+3} \bmod{2}) = (2a_{n+2} \bmod{2}) + (a_{n+1} \bmod{2})=0+1=1. $$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Since $2a_n$ is even, the parity of $a_{n+1}$ equals the parity of $a_{n-1}$.